# Generate dynamic forms and update database with comma separated values

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a web application for voting and I am trying to generate dynamic forms based on database information. Here's my models.py

```
class ballot(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    options=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_posted=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    results=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    active=models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I was wondering if it is possible for values in the options field to be stored as a comma separated list such as 'option1,option2,option3' and this would be parsed to generate 3 radio buttons. Similarly, results would be also be a comma separated list that would match up with options, such as '0,0,0' in this case. So if the second radio button was selected and submitted, the results in the database would update to '0,1,0'